# Backend is not available in the list of defined system mappings in Cloud connector

Tags: hana, sap-web-ide, sap-cloud-connector

While creating destination to my hana system. I face the error 'Backend is not available in the list of defined system mappings in Cloud connector' in the connection test.

The connection in cloud connector is reachable. I read through blogs, the virtual and internal address doesn't mismatch. the url doesn't have any '_', but still I face the error. Any leads to this kind of issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is resolved by deleting the location id in the destination settings

Comment: You can accept your own answer to let others know that the issue is resolved.